# How to adjust AG Grid Table column width with the corresponding rows?

Tags: css, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

The problem appeared after adding `drag and drop` to the rows, which was working fine while adding the checkboxes.

First I tried to apply `margin-left` to the `header checkbox wrapper div` in `Devtools` and it worked, but after trying to implement the style with css classes, it applied the given style to all rows.
 I assume, I am not targeting the correct classNames or maybe I need to make a use of cellStyles. 
Here is the link for the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wind-e3mge?file=/src/App.js) 
See the screenshot of current view

[image]

Targeting style correctly in `devtools`

[image]

[image]

Trying to do the same in code which doesn't work

```
.ag-wrapper .ag-input-wrapper .ag-checkbox-input-wrapper {
  margin-left: 27px !important;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not targeting the correct className. 
 Here is the correct way of targeting, if anyone else is struggling with something similar.

```
.ag-header-cell:first-child {
  margin-left: 26px;
}
```

And [working sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wind-e3mge?file=/src/styles.css)